# Running R script in Excel using Shell command in VBA

Tags: r, vba, excel, shell

I am using some code I took from here; [Run R function in VBA macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40349796/run-r-function-in-vba-macro)

```vb
Sub RunRscript()
'runs an external R code through Shell
'The location of the RScript is 'C:/Users/abhishek.b.jai/Downloads/data'
'The script name is 'testcode.R'
Dim shell As Object
Set shell = VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Dim waitTillComplete As Boolean: waitTillComplete = True
Dim style As Integer: style = 1
Dim errorCode As Integer
Dim path As String
path = "C:/Users/abhishek.b.jai/Downloads/data/testcode.r"
errorCode = shell.Run(path, style, waitTillComplete)
End Sub
```

I'm also using the same code itself but getting the error: Run-time error 429 mentioning "**ActiveX component can't create object**". 
Please help me with this issue.
Thank You!

Comment: Are you running this on a mac?

Comment: Check your references?

Comment: check this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18306362/run-r-script-from-command-line

Comment: the path of the script is not your entire command, you have to precede it with `Rscript` or `R CMD BATCH`

Comment: please elaborate @Moody_Mudskipper

Comment: Code:  Public Sub RunRTest()
           shell ("""C:\Users\abhishek.b.jai\Documents\R\R-
           3.4.0\bin\RScript""             
           C:\Users\abhishek.b.jai\Downloads\data\testcode.R")
           End Sub                                                                                          similar code is running but nothing happens in R.

Comment: What should your testcode script do ? What do you want to happen ? Do I understand correctly that your last piece of code doesn't return an error ?

Comment: Yes. I just want to run a Rscript from Excel itself using the VBA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably take a look at this.

http://rcom.univie.ac.at/download.html

Also, consider doing it this way.

```
Sub RunRscript()
'runs an external R code through Shell
'The location of the RScript is 'C:\R_code'
'The script name is 'hello.R'

Dim shell As Object
Set shell = VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Dim waitTillComplete As Boolean: waitTillComplete = True
Dim style As Integer: style = 1
Dim errorCode As Integer
Dim path As String
path = "RScript C:\R_code\hello.R"
errorCode = shell.Run(path, style, waitTillComplete)
End Sub
```

Look closely at the path...

https://www.howtogeek.com/181774/why-windows-uses-backslashes-and-everything-else-uses-forward-slashes/